# Find and replace string values in list while looping

Tags: python, list-comprehension, enumerate

I have a List that contains names of items (item01,item02 etc) 
i Would like to remove some of the old items and add new items in a list

i tried this code:

```
add_items = 'item22,item23'.split(',')
rmv_items = 'item01,item02'.split(',')
cur_kit_compon = ['item01', 'item02', 'item03', 'item4', 'item5']

for index, x in enumerate(add_items):
    new_kit_compon = [y.replace(rmv_items[index], x) for y in cur_kit_compon]

print('-------------------------')
print(new_kit_compon)
```

Code output:

```
['item01', 'item23', 'item03', 'item4', 'item5']
```

The problem: 
The code is only removing and adding 1 item instead of 2 items

Desired Output:

```
['item22', 'item23', 'item03', 'item4', 'item5']
```

Thank you for all your help

Comment: Other answers are perfect. Your code however can "work" if you just copy `cur_kit_compon` before your for loop (`new_kit_compon = cur_kit_compon[:]`) and then change your list comprehension to take items from this new list (`new_kit_compon = [y.replace(rmv_items[index], x) for y in new_kit_compon]`). This is not efficient and not recommended, but it might help you understand why your code was only replacing one item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a dictionary mapping the items to remove to their replacements, then use that dictionary to find the replacements for items in your list.

```
add_items = 'item22,item23'.split(',')
rmv_items = 'item01,item02'.split(',')

replacements = dict(zip(rmv_items, add_items))

cur_kit_compon = ['item01', 'item02', 'item03', 'item4', 'item5']
res = [replacements.get(item, item) for item in cur_kit_compon]
# ['item22', 'item23', 'item03', 'item4', 'item5']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're nesting a list comprehension inside of a `for` loop, when there's no reason to do so. Instead of

```
for index, x in enumerate(add_items):
    new_kit_compon = [y.replace(rmv_items[index], x) for y in cur_kit_compon]
```

just do

```
new_kit_compon = cur_kit_compon[:]         # create a copy of original list, so as not to modify it
for add, rmv in zip(add_items, rmv_items): # go through the added and removed items together
    idx = new_kit_compon.index(rmv)        # find the index of the item to replace
    new_kit_compon[idx] = add              # replace it
print(new_kit_compon)
```

Comment: This is still O(n**2), as `index` has to look through the list on each loop.

Comment: Also, will throw ValueError if `rmv` is not in `cur_kit_compon`

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do the following? If the idea is to get the list with updated items

```
add_items+[item for item in cur_kit_compon if item not in rmv_items]
```

Output

```
['item22', 'item23', 'item03', 'item4', 'item5']
```

Comment: That will do too - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the values from the while saving it to the new list every loop. The old list (`cur_kit_compon`) stays the same. E.g.:

```
add_items = 'item22,item23'.split(',')
rmv_items = 'item01,item02'.split(',')
cur_kit_compon = ['item01', 'item02', 'item03', 'item4', 'item5']

for index, x in enumerate(add_items):
    new_kit_compon = [y.replace(rmv_items[index], x) for y in cur_kit_compon]
    print('cur_kit_compon: ', cur_kit_compon)
```

result:

```
print('-------------------------')
print(new_kit_compon)
cur_kit_compon:  ['item01', 'item02', 'item03', 'item4', 'item5']
cur_kit_compon:  ['item01', 'item02', 'item03', 'item4', 'item5']
-------------------------
['item01', 'item23', 'item03', 'item4', 'item5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through `cur_kit_compon` and replace items according to `add_items/rmv_items` found indices:

```
add_items = 'item22,item23'.split(',')
rmv_items = 'item01,item02'.split(',')
cur_kit_compon = ['item01', 'item02', 'item03', 'item4', 'item5']
for index, item in enumerate(cur_kit_compon):
    if item in rmv_items:
        i = rmv_items.index(item)
        cur_kit_compon[index] = add_items[i]
cur_kit_compon
```